# Powerpoint Visual Basic code not working

Tags: vba, dictionary, powerpoint

Recently I have been using a lot of macro visual basic in my PowerPoint. Everything was working fine and then I needed to add a `Try` and `Catch` statement. It seemed not to work but I thought maybe it changed in newer versions. Now after trying to make a dictionary in visual basic using PowerPoint the same thing happened. It didn't work and the text was red.

This is the code for the dictionary:

```
Dim test As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
test.Add("1", 1)
```

Is there anyway of adding dictionaries to it when using PowerPoint? or is this code wrong? The same thing with try and catch statements?

Comment: You seem to be trying to use VB.NET instead of VBA?  They're not the same.

Comment: VBA does not have try catch you will need `On Error GoTo`. VBA is a beast all of it's own

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure the reference to System.Collections.Generic is declared.

At the top of your code add:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
```

Comment: Is this only for dictionaries?

Comment: Yes and everything else in that collection.

Answer (score 1):

You are very unclear on the end result but try something like this.

```
Sub test()
On Error Goto Handler
    Dim test AS New Collection
    test.Add "1", "27"
    test.Add 15, "Monkeys"
    Exit Sub
Handler:
    Msgbox "Error Number: " & Err & " Occurred. Its message text is: " & Error(Err)
End Sub
```

VBA Does not have `Try` and `Catch` you must handle all errors with `On Error GoTo` then you can process the Errors by the Error Number. [See Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146864)

Also note I used a `Collection` which uses an `Item` and `Key` structure. Not sure what you are going for with this but you can retrieve Items by `Key` in a `Collection` which might be fine for you. e.g.

```
 test.Item(1) 'will return "1" by index
 test.Item("27") 'will return "1" by key
 test.Item(2) ' will return 15 by index
 test.Item("Monkeys") 'will return 15 by key
```

Comment: Thank you! On the internet is said to use dictionaries. It look so far like collections are working :)

Comment: Ok so everything was working fine creating it but when I added to it it gave me the error "type mismatch" || Dim test As New Collection -- test.Add "1", 1

Comment: @user1541397 Sorry I apologize fixed my answer `Collection` uses `object,string` so the integer is what is causing it to fail. Also I changed the key to show you retrieval methods. If you submit an integer it assumes you want the index, with a string it is looking for a key.